# Does JQuery $.post() not work with document.onbeforeunload event?

Tags: javascript, dom, onbeforeunload, jquery-post

I am trying to use $.post to send form data to a server side script to be saved if the user tries to leave the page without submitting the form.  I am using the same function attached to a save button and on setInterval set to every 2 minutes, and it works fine.  But when I attach the function to document.onbeforeunload it does not work.  In firebug, I see the request is being sent, but it looks like it is being stopped before a status code is returned and the page continues to unload.  I am still pretty new to Javascript and Jquery and I am not sure if maybe $.post is one of those functions that might not work on the onbeforeunload event.  If that is true, is there another way I can send the data if the user tries to leave the page without saving?

```
This is the function I am calling from the onbeforeunload event:

           function ajaxSubmit(){
                var blogtitle = $("#title").val();
                var publishedstate = 0;
                var blogid = $("#blogID").val();
                var blogbody = CKEDITOR.instances['body'].getData();

                var postdata = {ajaxSubmit:true,title:blogtitle,body:blogbody,published:publishedstate,blog_id:blogid};
                $.post('ajaxblog.php',postdata,function(data){
                    $("#autosaveMessage").html(data);
                    $("#autosaveMessage").show();
                    setTimeout(function(){$("#autosaveMessage").hide();},5000);
                });
            }
```

and this is how I am calling the function:

```
               var post_clicked = false;
            $("#postButton").click(function(){
                post_clicked = true;
            });

            function leaveEditor(){
                if(post_clicked==false){
                    ajaxSubmit();
                }
                else{
                    //Do Nothing
                }
            }

window.onbeforeunload = leaveEditor;
```

Comment: I guess my problem is my misunderstanding of the onbeforeunload event.  Apparently if you attach a function to it, it looks for a returnValue object, specifically a string to use for a confirm box.  If it doesnt get a return value, it continues with dropping the resources and unloading the page.  Thought I would put this up in case anyone experiences the same problem. Tried not putting in callback function, and setTimeout, neither worked.  I will go with confirm box and everything working, but if someone knows a workaround so I don't have to have confirm box, I would appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and this is by design.  It would be remarkably troublesome if a page could use `onbeforeunload` to indefinitely delay browsing away, persist its presence somehow, etc.  One of the most important abilities for a user of a web browser to have is the ability to *leave*.

Just use the stringy return value—the whole point of it is to remind the user that s/he made changes that will be lost.  Like on SO  :)

Comment: Thanks, I kind of thought this might be the case after I read up on the onbeforeunload event a little.  It makes sense.