# how to run script onbeforeunload

Tags: php, javascript

hi somebody pls explain to me why this code of mine doesn't work

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {wireUpEvents(); 
    });

    function  wireUpEvents()
    {window.onbeforeunload = function()
        {
        window.location="link"; // on before unload i will run this link first.
        }
    }
```

when i refresh my page this code will run but it'll not go to link(window.location) before load however when i add alert like this

```
window.location="link"; alert("anything");
```

it'll go to my link before load. I like to eliminate that weird alert().

pls feel free to suggest any treatment with my code. thanks

Comment: did you included jquery ?AFAIK you are using jquery too

Comment: yes is am @NullPointer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does JQuery $.post() not work with document.onbeforeunload event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816512/does-jquery-post-not-work-with-document-onbeforeunload-event)

Comment: the gist of that question's answer is: no, you can't do this, because the page is already changing and will immediately continue to do so.  as soon as the current page is unloaded, your request is cancelled.  you need to poll instead.

Comment: @Eevee now i know.big help thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try below code

```
window.onbeforeunload=testfunc;

function testfunc()
{
window.location="link";
}
```

Comment: yeah that one will works no doubt. but what if inside that function i will direct it to my desired page before anything else.. thanks

Comment: @kodewrecker you can anything you want in that function.

Comment: i think i need to have a pause after this window.location = 'link' something alert will do, but i don't want that alert there its annoying

Comment: @kodewrecker remove that alert. I put it for letting you know that the function is working.

Comment: yeah i know, but if i dont put any stopper(alert,confirm) it bypass the link and continue to load. the link contain query's when i test it without stopper nothing change has been made to my data in db. weird

Comment: I think it'll work. please refresh your page. use ctrl+F5 . then see what o/p comes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { 
            window.location="link"; 
        } 
    );
</script>
```

Comment: dont know what is wrong i would like to direct it to page before load  coz i'll do some query, my code and yours were working. i have tried to call js function with that.